# Condense Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, duplicates, case

I am trying to find the number of orders with a combination of products 1 and 2 or 1 and 3. Right now I have the data but it is not combining the records into one, which I need.

I have used a case statement to get the count for each order to then bring into Excel to analyze.

```
select  
b.Order, 
CASE when Style in ('2','3') then '1' else '0' end as Pants,
CASE when Style = '1' then '1' else '0' end as Tunic
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.join1 = b.join1 
INNER JOIN c ON b.join2 = c.join2
 WHERE Style IN ('1','2','3')
 group by b.order, Style
 order by b.order
```

example output current:

```
order        pants        tunic
abc            1            0
abc            0            1
```

Example desired output:

```
order        pants        tunic
abc            1            1
```

Comment: What do the tables look like?

Answer (score 0):

use  aggregation

```
select  
b.Order, 
sum(CASE when Style in ('2','3') then 1 else 0 end) as Pants,
sum(CASE when Style = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Tunic
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.join1 = b.join1 
INNER JOIN c ON b.join2 = c.join2
 WHERE Style IN ('1','2','3')
 group by b.order, Style
 order by b.order
```

BTW what is the datatype of `Style` cause you used quote in condition it is ok if it is string type but in case of it is int then it should be `style=1`
and `style in (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation.  For an indicator, use `max()`, for a count, use `sum()`:

```
select b.Order, 
       max(case when Style in (2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) as Pants,
       max(case when Style = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  as Tunic
from a join
     b 
     on a.join1 = b.join1 join
     c
     on b.join2 = c.join2
where style in (1, 2, 3)
group by b.order
order by b.order;
```

Notes:

- The fix is removing `style` from the `group by` and adding the aggregation functions in the `select`.
- Do not use single quotes around numbers.
- I am assuming that `style` is a number, not a string, so I removed the single quotes.  If it is really a string, then use the single quotes.
- `order` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: I removed Style form the group by and used MAX instead of SUM as it is a varchar and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @joe . . . Are you trying to count the values or just add an indicator of 0/1?

Comment: get the indicator of whether the combination was purchased and then bring it into excel to analyze.